# C# MongoDB - Edit data nested 2 deep

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's imagine this data:

```
class A
{
    string Id_A;
    int MyInt;
}

class B
{
    ...
    string Id_B;
    List<A> MyListA;
}

class C
{
    ...
    string Id_C;
    List<B> MyListB;
}
```

and I have a Mongo collection with objects C

Is it possible / what is the syntax to do an update list this:

Find an object C through Id_C,
then find the right B object through Id_B in the MyList list,
then find the right A object through Id_A
and replace A:MyInt

The Linq equivalent for the search would be:

```
var Q = from c in CList where c.Id_C == "..."
        from b in c.MyListB where b.Id_B == "..."
        from a in b.MyListA where a.Id_A == "..."
        select a.MyInt;
```

but this:

```
    var Q = from c in Driver.AsQueryable() where c.Id_C == "c0"
            from b in c.MyListB where b.Id_B == "b0"
            from a in b.MyListA where a.Id_A == "a1" select a.MyInt;

    return q.First();
```

does not work and gives this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: '$project or $group does not support
>   {document}.

Comment: What version of mongodb server do you use ?

Comment: I'm using 3.6, the latest.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB shell:

```
db.collection.update({Id_C:'...', "MyListB.Id_B":'...' , "MyListB.MyListA.Id_A":'...'},{$set:{"MyListB.$.MyListA.0.MyInt":<number>}})
```

Where `collection` is your collection of `C` objects.

Also, since you're using 3.6, you could use [expressive updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#specify-arrayfilters-for-an-array-update-operations).

Comment: My question is specifically about the C# syntax: how do you create the update with "MyListB.$.MyListA.0.MyInt" with the C# driver?

Comment: Also, I can do a filter with one embedded list with (c => c.IdC == "..." && c.MyListB.Any(b => b.Id_b == "...")) but how do I add a third term to filter inside B:MyListA?